# ng-bootstrap / in case of multiple ngbNav in same page, contents are never displayed but those of first instantiaed ngbNav

Tags: ng-bootstrap, ng-template

**[ng-bootstrap]** in case of multiple ngbNav on same page, contents of second and below navs are never displayed with ngbNavOutlet directives, but the first only (looks like it can recall ng-template of first ngbNav only).
thx for your help.

Comment: stackblitz would be very useful

Comment: Sure !
Check this out :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y47v4r

You can see that content of second nav are never displayed but instead those of first nav..
must be a template reference issue somewhere...

Comment: thanks! now it is clear and the answer provided.
ps, it would nice to leverage semantic HTML and use `nav` tag instead. with such a tiny change you will make life easier for blind folks.  more on semantic HTML https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see there is the same id used for the first and the second nav panels. Just make it unique and both nav panel will work well.

[image: the same id highlightetd in the code]

Comment: I made some semantic changes as u recommended.
However i can't make it to work by changing to unique ID as it brings up compile errors:
- changing ngbNavOutlet yells this error : "Property 'nav1' does not exist on type 'NgbdNavMarkup'."
- changing #nav claims this one : "No directive found with exportAs 'ngbNav1'."

you can have a look this new test : 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-spwknh

Thans for ur help again

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-spwknh-f3xhfg?file=src/app/nav-markup.html
Changes are in lines 19 and 34

Comment: you are welcome! don't forget to mark the answer as a valid one (:

Answer (score 0):

Use the attribute from the API domId

```
[domId]="unique-id-here"
```

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/nav/api